# Error while running Powershell Script in o365

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, user-profile-property

Hi Below is the error i am getting while running the powershell script
Error

Cannot find an overload for "PeopleManager" and the argument count: "1

**Script:**

```
#Importing PowerShell Module
    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking


#Authenticating User to SharePoint Online
   $username = "test@domainO365Dev.onmicrosoft.com" 
   $Adminurl = "https://sp-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev"
   $siteColUrl = "https://test365dev.sharepoint.com"

#Logging Method for errors
   $DATE = get-date
   $LogPath = "logpath"
   $LogFileName = "LogFileName.log"

$FilePath = $LogPath +"\" + $LogFileName
$logFileCreated = $False
function write-log([string]$label, [string]$logMsg)
{ 

    if($logFileCreated -eq $False)
    {
        write-host "Creating log file..."
        if((Test-Path -path $LogPath) -ne $True)
        {
            write-host"Provide proper values to LogPath folder" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $logHeader
            $script:logFileCreated  = $True
            write-host "Log file created..."
            [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
        Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
    }
 }

try
{
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


   #Bind to site collection
   $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteColUrl)
   $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$Password)
   $Context.Credentials = $Creds
   Write-Host "Successfully connected.." -ForegroundColor Green


   #Retrieve lists
   $web = $Context.Web
   $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
   $Context.Load($Users)
   $Context.Load($web)
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()

   $PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
    Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {  
      $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
      Write-Host "user profile value: " + $UserProfile
      $Context.ExecuteQuery()
      If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
          Write-Host "User:" $UserProfile.Email -ForegroundColor Green
          $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties
        }  
    }
}
  catch
       { 
          write-log "Error: " $_.Exception.Message
  }
```

Comment: Can you give some details on the error? Line in script or so? I commented out the first line (`Import-Module`) but the rest of the script ran fine for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are referring 2013 Client SDK dll's.. Look the path points to `15` hive

You should install SPO Client SDK and change to `16` hive in `Add-Type`

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Comment: I did as you suggested, the issue still persists

Comment: Chaning the path to 16 hive did the trick.. I think there was some caching problem in the powershell management shell

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not binding to the right context. If you are working with the UserProfile, you need to bind your context to the My Site host, `https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com`.